# Jack-Jack's powers

Tags: character, incredibles-2

In the movie [Incredibles 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3606756/) Jack-Jack was one of the best part of the entire movie. In the entire run of the movie, Jack-Jack's many different powers are shown, ranging from Laser eyes to Angry Demon.

My question is, **in total, Jack-Jack has how many powers?**

If there's an article or an interview mentioning the powers, it would be the best.

Comment: All of them. He's Jack of all trades.

Answer (score 10):

(Spoiler alert - if you haven't watched the movie yet)

Jack Jack has demonstrated 17 different powers in the movie
They are

- Electrokinesis (When Bob discovered Jack Jack Had powers, baby demonstrates it for a moment),
- Transforming into the metal (as scene in First Movie against Syndrome),
- Levitation
- Super strength Resistance Durability (against raccoon scene),
- Human Torch (Fire baby throughout the movie),
- Rocket Jump (During sneezes),
- Reality Distortion (in the car incredible scene)
- Cloning Himself (Duplicates)
- Mimicry and shapeshifting(at Edna's home)
- Demon Baby
- Elastic Baby (when raccoon try to pull his face, kind of rubbery feel)
- Giant Baby, (Juggernaut moment)
- Teleportation, (Cookie Scenes)
- Phasing (phase through glass doors and walls)
- Interdimensional travel (Cookie scene)
- Telekenisis (closing lids, removing hyponsis googles)
- Laser Vision (The best
  among all)

Comment: This would be better if it listed them with examples of where he used it. A really good answer might have a shot of each power in use, and imo would attract good upvotes.

Comment: You can take some clue from here too https://screenrant.com/incredibles-2-jack-jack-powers-explained/

Comment: pew pew, pew pew pew!

Comment: I assumed his main power was to be able to transform into other things (as you mention: giant, elastic, demon etc). On the other-hand, maybe "Reality Distortion" is his only ability.